# Laravel Push to session creates sublevel

Tags: php, laravel, session

I have a session with the following structure:

```
array: [
  "origin" => "us"
  "destination" => "bd"
  ]
]
```

when I do:

```
$order = [ "url" => $request->url, "quantity" => $request->quantity ];

session()->push('order', $order);
```

The result is:

```
array: [
  "origin" => "us"
  "destination" => "bd"
  0 => array:2 [▼
     "url" => "url"
     "quantity" => "1"
  ]
]
```

I don't want that 0, I want the "url" and "quantity" right on the root level, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing wrong is your are pushing the entire array into the session. Instead of pushing the array, push it value instead. Just add key => value pairs.

```
session([
    "url" => $request->url, // or "url" => $order["url"]
    "quantity" => $request->quantity // or "quantity" => $order["quantity"]
]);
```

That's it. They will be at the root of your session. `session()` is simply the session global helper.